# HTML table customizing last 2 rows

Tags: html, css

I have a table:

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>       
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($draftOrderProducts as $draftOrderProduct)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_quantity'] }}</td>
                <td>${{ $draftOrderProduct['products_price'] }}</td>
                <td>${{ $draftOrderProduct['final_price'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td><b>Grand Total<b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td></td> // empty bordered table data which I want to get rid of
        <td>${{ $grandTotal }}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

As you can see, I am using empty `td`'s to "almost" achieve my goal. My goal is to have 2 last rows, with 2 td's aligned to the right for the grand total. I would prefer not having empty bordered td's on their left however (but need to keep the right alignement of the "grand total" td's.

Comment: Any code or css div you can use for this will for sure be bigger than leaving those TDs alone. Tables are good and professional just as divs. Dont lysten to others sayngs divs are better than tables because is not true. There is nothing better than tables and those ugly TDs for what you need so just leave it like this. Example <div style bla bla bla</div> you see? more core than those TDs

Comment: now to avoid borders in those TDs simply add the follow <td style="border:0"> to each TD you dont want border and you are done

Comment: `Colspan` will help you here, and you can do what you want, but also consider condensing those two rows into 1: http://jsfiddle.net/up4vtvtq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get rid of all empty `td's` you need to use atleast one. Just use `colspan` . try this which is the closest match for what you're looking to achieve:

```
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td>${{ $grandTotal }}}</td>
```

If you still want to remove the border around the border around the extra `td`, unfortunately there isn't a clean way. But you can achieve it by a CSS trick. try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>       
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach($draftOrderProducts as $draftOrderProduct)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_name'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $draftOrderProduct['products_quantity'] }}</td>
                <td>${{ $draftOrderProduct['products_price'] }}</td>
                <td>${{ $draftOrderProduct['final_price'] }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="final" colspan="4"></td> 
            <td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="final" colspan="4"></td> 
            <td>${{ $grandTotal }}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And use the CSS:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
.final{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/up4vtvtq/)

Comment: Thanks. However there are still lines that I'd like to remove. Please check: http://screencast.com/t/dvv441oo Basically the lines that are red should not be there

Answer (score 1):

Tables are a bit painful.  **colspan** is probably your best bet here.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td> 
    <td><b>Grand Total<b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td> 
    <td>${{ $grandTotal }}}</td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:** As far as styling tables goes they're pretty damn stubborn and you will need some css magic to get the desired outcome here in regards to borders.

This should acheive what you're after:

```
<style>
table { 
   width: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
tfoot td:first-child {
    border: none !important;
}
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>       
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($draftOrderProducts as $draftOrderProduct)
            <tr>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
                <td>car</td>
                <td>sa</td>
                <td>bla</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td> 
            <td><b>Grand Total</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td> 
            <td>${{ $grandTotal }}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. However there are still lines that I'd like to remove. Please check: screencast.com/t/dvv441oo Basically the lines that are red should not be there

Comment: Theres no colour in that image?  Which lines?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `colspan` attribute for the `td` element. In this case `<td colspan='5'>sample text</td>`. Then you can align or float right.

Replace:

```
<td><b>Grand Total<b></td>
```

With:

```
<td colspan='5'><b>Grand Total<b></td>
```